# how can i get validation error in controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, message

im posting some textfields data to controller using ajax method without using form ,
now i want to get validation error msgs if any field is kept empty in controller through modelstate , so how can I??

```
 public JsonResult Check(Employee emp)
    {          
        string msg = null;
        bool success = false;
        if(ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            success = true;                           
        }
        else {
            return Json(new { msg = ModelState });
        }

        return Json(emp);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add attributes to the properties in the Employee viewmodel that are required as follows:

```
[Required]
public string Name {get; set;}
```

This [post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/adding-validation-to-the-model) provides some more details as to different types of validation you can add.

Comment: So are you able to post data to the controller action in your example? Are any of the employee fields set, and what is the status of IsValid on modelstate?